# Vue property undefined

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am trying to finish one of the FreeCodeCamp challenges.  It's a random quote generator and I finally found an API site that works on CodePen.

My issue is that it appears to work.  I run the script and it gives me a random quote, thus the API and the `fetch()` work.  But the console keeps giving me a `cannot read property 'quote' of undefined`, which then breaks my JavaScript and won't let me click on my button to get another one.

I'm using Vue here, and I'm fairly new to Vue.  I've actually never used Vue before today, but after going through the introduction at Vue.js, I thought I could at least handle this, so I decided to do this with Vue.  From what I do understand, I don't get how the quotes array is undefined.  There are 10 quotes in my JSON file and the random function is inclusive, so it'll only grab 0-9, so it's not an issue of index out of bounds.

Here's the relevant code (an .html file and a .js file):

```
<h1>Random Quote Generator</h1>

<div id="quote-block">
  <span id="quote">{{ quotes[index].quote }}</span>
  <p><span id="author">-{{ quotes[index].author }}</span></p>
  <p><button id="new-quote">New Quote</button></p>
</div>

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#quote-block',
    data: {
      quotes: [],
      index: random(0,9)
    },
    created() {
      fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fb9jb')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => this.quotes = json.quotes)
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
      currentColor = colorize();
    },
    // getQuotes: ()=> {
    //   this.index = random(0,9);
    //   currentColor = colorize();
    // }
});
```

And the full code pen (the rest is just a random color generator and mouseovers unrelated to Vue or this problem) is here: https://codepen.io/jkuhl/pen/JMrxGV?editors=1010

The commented code was going to be the implemented click event code using @click

I get this error any time I try to access the values of the objects in the quotes array.  I can access the quotes array itself, those values show up no problem.  Like if I do {{ quotes}} instead of {{quotes[index].quote }} I get the whole array to show up just fine.  It's when I try to access the values of the objects in the array, that my script breaks.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're seeing is caused by trying to bind the value of `quotes[index].quote` before your quotes are fetched, so you need to conditionally render that portion by using `v-if`:

```
<div id="quote-block" v-if="quotes.length">
  <span id="quote">{{ quotes[index].quote }}</span>
  <p><span id="author">-{{ quotes[index].author }}</span></p>
  <p><button id="new-quote">New Quote</button></p>
</div>
```

This will render the `div` only when the length of your quotes array is greater than zero. Other than this you should try organizing your code more to the 'vue way' of doing things like the other answer says.

Comment: That fixed it.  I figured it was something like that, but wasn't sure exactly what it was or how to fix it.  Again, brand new to Vue, thought I'd mess with it.  I'm probably making this codepen more complicated than it needs to be with it, but oh well.  It's a learning experience.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, functions in vue components need to be in a `methods` object, just like `data`. Refer: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html. You can then set the listener for an element in HTML using v-on: `<button id="new-quote" v-on:click="getQuotes">New Quote</button>`

I got your code to work simply by following the correct pattern as in the link above.

Here's the relevant code.

HTML:

```
<div id="quote-block">
  <span id="quote">{{ quotes[index].quote }}</span>
  <p><span id="author">-{{ quotes[index].author }}</span></p>
  <p><button id="new-quote" v-on:click="getQuotes">New Quote</button></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#quote-block',
    data: {
      quotes: [],
      index: random(0,9)
    },
    created() {
      fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fb9jb')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => this.quotes = json.quotes)
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
      currentColor = colorize();
    },
    methods: {
      getQuotes: function (event) {
        this.index = random(0,9);
        currentColor = colorize();
      } 
    }
  }); //End Vue
```

You can see the full pen at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/odBbLW?editors=1011 (I've removed some colourizer code for brevity). It still gives an error at load, but the button works.

Bonus tip: Wrapping your code in an anonymous self-executing function means you can't refer to the variables defined in that scope in the console. So you can't do `app.$data.quotes` in the codepen/devtools console, which just makes debugging hard. There's no need to use anonymous self-executing functions when you're just testing small things out like this.

Comment: Thanks.  I kind of figured my click event wasn't going to work, and I was going to just head over to Vue.js and look that up once I figured out why I was getting this "undefined" error.